# Can I migrate from GNU Mailman to MailChimp?

Tags: email, mailchimp

I have ~20 lists, all of which are mostly announce-only (newsletters--recipients do not reply back to the list) running in GNU Mailman. It's alright. Mailman has certainly prooven itself but we want some progressive features and a better peice of mind (delivery success, hosting, etc... we'd be happy paying a 3rd party to handle these things).

can MailChimp give us what we need? I see tons of fun copy and graphics, showing off neat features but what I really want to do is; if MailChimp is doing the mailings, what does the address look like? is MailChimp good for sending out simple newsletters? What about automatic bounce processing / unsubscribing of users?

I setup a free account but I don't see how any of it integrates into my own domain... no DNS overrides or cname suggestions.

Also, I see MailChimp has a clean and nifty API client in Python that I want to integrate into our sites (Django powered) so that really really makes the service attractive to me--I just hope I understand it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

It is going to be impossible for someone who doesn't know your exact business needs to say for certain that MailChimp is the right service for you, but it is one hell of a good service and does everything you have said it needs to do in your question.

Maybe some type of phased rollout would be the way forward, move one of your lists over to it and see how that works out, then look at moving the others across.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using MailChimp for over a year now, I started out as a free user but I am more than happy to pay the monthly fees that I am currently incurring.

The good thing about MC is that it lets you directly import large email lists without an opt-in feature (which feature I could not find in Aweber).

There is no need to integrate your domain with MC, since the email delivery is handled by them (so the email header looks like Your Name via MC). They do provide you some pretty cool forms that you can embed in your site and MC will take care of the rest.

MC handles automatic bounces, it also has a default unsubscribe link all the emailers (which is good, since you don't want to pay for those subscribers anyway!!). MC also has a pretty useful feature called as Golden Monkeys, which lets you tag prospective customers and track their each and every activity.